# Formatting a list of strings as a comma-separated string

Tags: haskell, formatting

I'm learning Haskell on my own and I'm following the material of a course.

I would like to know if this is idiomatic Haskell.

```
asList :: [String] -> String
asList ss = "[" ++ (concat $ intersperse "," ss) ++ "]"
```

Comment: I have arbitrarily chosen one of your four questions. You should ask about the other three functions in separate posts. If you ask about `insertBST`, you should probably include the corresponding `searchBST` function in that question too.

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag would instruct reviewers to refrain from giving you complete solutions. Since you have indicated that you are writing code for a self-study course, I have removed the [homework] tag for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks idiomatic to me.

There's one slight improvement to the code that I could come up with.  There is a function that does what you're doing in the middle, called `intercalate`.  Here's the definition, from [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#intercalate):

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate xs xss = concat (intersperse xs xss)
```

Using that, your function becomes:

```
asList :: [String] -> String
asList ss = "[" ++ (intercalate "," ss) ++ "]"
```

Comment: Beautiful! When I wrote asList, I actually remember seeing intercalate - but did not take the mental leap to consider a a Char. (I considered a as String, in which case it is not as useful).

Comment: Perhaps - you could include the performance comparison in your answer? It is interesting/useful enough not to be hidden in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator should be used sparingly, and especially avoided after long lists.  In this case, the `++ "]"` at the end would require walking down nearly the entire constructed string to append the final character.

Here is an implementation that avoids that problem:

```
asList :: [String] -> String
asList ss = '[' : asList' ss
  where
    asList' (a:b:ss) = a ++ (',' : asList' (b:ss))
    asList' (a:ss)   = a ++ asList' (ss)
    asList' []       = "]"
```

Comment: OK I see, thanks. To me, this is sacrificing readability for performance - is it common to go to this extent to avoid ++ operator? Or is that only done for performance-critical functions?

Comment: This was also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188286/idiomatic-efficient-haskell-append

Comment: I agree that your original code is more readable. In the end, it's up to you to decide whether readability or performance is more important.

Comment: I tried this with `replicate 50000000 "abc"` as input, and on my machine in GHCI using `:set +s`, the OP's code runs in about 3.5 seconds, and your code runs in about 35 seconds.  I tried writing a bit of code that used `foldr (:)` to avoid the `++` at the end, assuming it would be faster.  My code ran in about 4.2 seconds.